# WebsocketServerContainer not in ServletContext after Tomcat-Update

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-websocket

I just upgraded my local tomcat (windows maschine), from 9.0.10 to 9.0.14.
Now i am getting the following Stacktrace when starting my Spring Application (Spring Boot 2.1.1: MVC, Security, Websocket, Session).

Any ideas why this is happening, are there any known changes in tomcat? I looked for the changelog, but nothing there.

Thx for any advice or help!

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'createWebSocketContainer' defined in class path resource [com/my/spring/ws/MyWebsocketConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attribute 'javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer' not found in ServletContext
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:827)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
    at com.my.spring.MyApplication.run(MyApplication.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
    at com.my.spring.MyApplication.onStartup(MyApplication.java:40)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5120)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 42 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attribute 'javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer' not found in ServletContext
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.ServletServerContainerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ServletServerContainerFactoryBean.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741)
    ... 63 more
```

**Update:**

After removing the Bean, everything is working fine again.
But this is no option, because i need to increase the message limits.
Is there another way of doing this?

```
    @Bean
    public ServletServerContainerFactoryBean createWebSocketContainer() {
        ServletServerContainerFactoryBean container = new ServletServerContainerFactoryBean();
        container.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(1024 * 1024 * 5);
        container.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(1024 * 1024 * 5);
        return container;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like that to configure message size:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    ...

    @Override
    public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registration) {
        registration.setMessageSizeLimit(3184700); // default : 64 * 1024
        registration.setSendTimeLimit(20 * 10000); // default : 10 * 10000
        registration.setSendBufferSizeLimit(3 * 512 * 1024); // default : 512 * 1024

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue after spring boot update, looks like we need to provide the websocket servlet bean as well if we configure ServletServerContainerFactoryBean explicitly.

Try adding:

> ```
> @Bean
> public TomcatWebSocketServletWebServerCustomizer tomcatWebSocketServletWebServerCustomizer() {
>     return new TomcatWebSocketServletWebServerCustomizer();
> }
> ```

Worked for me.